# Owl Carousel 2 server side rendering in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, owl-carousel-2

I am working on Owl Carousel 2. I want to give support in server side rendering Is it possible in Reactjs using yarn? please give me an example of server side rendering using Reactjs for Owl Carousel 2.

Answer (score 1):

I used loadable to be able to import the library and it worked fine with SSR.

First install loadable:

```
npm install @loadable/component
```

Import the component in your JS file

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component';
```

Then I imported ReactOwlCarousel as below:

```
const ReactOwlCarousel = loadable(() => import('react-owl-carousel'), { ssr: false });
return <ReactOwlCarousel... />
```

Hope this helps someone!